# Determining the Length of a String Literal

Tags: c, arrays, string, literals

Given an array of pointers to string literals:

```
char *textMessages[] = {
    "Small text message",
    "Slightly larger text message",
    "A really large text message that "
    "is spread over multiple lines"
}
```

How does one determine the length of a particular string literal - say the third one? I have tried using the sizeof command as follows:

```
int size = sizeof(textMessages[2]);
```

But the result seems to be the number of pointers in the array, rather than the length of the string literal.

Comment: `sizeof(textMessages[2])` will yield the size of the `char*` type.   It's purely coincidental that `sizeof(char*)` happens to be 4 on your system, and nothing to do with the number of elements in your array.

Comment: You should consider using the definition `static const char textMesssages[][4]` for your array.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis There are only *three* pointers in the array (note the string concatenation).

Comment: @Jens: Oh well, my point didn't really lie in the choice of number, although I'd advocate for having a sentinel value.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you want the number computed at *compile time* (as opposed to at runtime with `strlen`) it is perfectly okay to use an expression like

```
sizeof "A really large text message that "
       "is spread over multiple lines";
```

You might want to use a macro to avoid repeating the long literal, though:

```
#define LONGLITERAL "A really large text message that " \
                    "is spread over multiple lines"
```

Note that the value returned by `sizeof` includes the terminating NUL, so is one more than `strlen`.

Comment: I wish to determine the length of each string so that I can index the lengths and pass them to a function. Is it possible to compute such an array of lengths at compile time?

Comment: My approach would be to declare and initialize an array of `struct { char *ptr; size_t len; } x[]`. Then you can call `foo(x[i].ptr, x[i].len)`. Since C doesn't keep string lengths around, there is no other way than to keep track of string lengths in your code.

Answer (score 21):

My suggestion would be to use **strlen** and turn on compiler optimizations.

For example, with gcc 4.7 on x86:

```
#include <string.h>
static const char *textMessages[3] = {
    "Small text message",
    "Slightly larger text message",
    "A really large text message that "
    "is spread over multiple lines"
};

size_t longmessagelen(void)
{
  return strlen(textMessages[2]);
}
```

After running `make CFLAGS="-ggdb -O3" example.o`:

```
$ gdb example.o
(gdb) disassemble longmessagelen
   0x00000000 <+0>: mov    $0x3e,%eax
   0x00000005 <+5>: ret
```

I.e. the compiler has replaced the call to `strlen` with the constant value 0x3e = 62.

Don't waste time performing optimizations that the compiler can do for you!

Comment: Does gcc know how to optimize this because it is part of the standard library, or will it optimize if we hand-rolled a string length counter?  I think I'll test it...

Answer (score 1):

**strlen** gives you the length of string whereas **sizeof** will return the size of the **Data Type** in Bytes you have entered as parameter.

[strlen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78zh94ax%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

[sizeof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s7x1k91.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could exploit the fact, that values in an array are consecutive:

```
const char *messages[] = {
    "footer",
    "barter",
    "banger"
};

size_t sizeOfMessage1 = (messages[1] - messages[0]) / sizeof(char); // 7   (6 chars + '\0')
```

The size is determined by using the boundaries of the elements. The space between the beginning of the first and beginning of the second element is the size of the first.

This includes the terminating `\0`. The solution, of course, does only work properly with constant strings. If the strings would've been pointers, you would get the size of a pointer instead the length of the string.

**This is not guaranteed to work**. If the fields are aligned, this may yield wrong sizes and there may be other caveats introduced by the compiler, like merging identical strings.
Also you'll need at least two elements in your array.

Comment: This is not guaranteed to work. While the pointers in the array must be consecutive, the string literals need not. Think of alignment and such. Or using the same pointer for identical string literals.

Comment: You're right, alignment would break this (but that's controllable). Different sizes for `char` would break this, too. I'll mark my answer as not reliable.

Comment: Merging identical strings, a common optimization, also breaks it.

Answer (score 1):

`strlen` is slow and potentially executed in run-time. Whereas `sizeof("string_literal") - 1` is fast and executed at compile-time. The problem is how to use `sizeof` on string literals pointed at by your pointer array - we can't.

Now assuming you want this as fast as possible and also done at compile-time for performance reasons... Everything in C is possible if you throw enough ugly macros at the problem. Here's such a solution that favours performance and maintainability at the cost of readability.

We can move the string initializer list out of the array and into a macro. For example by declaring so-called "X-macros", like this:

```
#define STRING_LIST(X)                     \
  X("Small text message")                  \
  X("Slightly larger text message")        \
  X("A really large text message that "    \
    "is spread over multiple lines")
```

This macro can now be reused for various purposes, by defining another macro and passing it as parameter "X" to the above list. For example the array declaration could be done as:

```
#define STRING_INIT_LIST(str) str,
char *textMessages[] = 
{
  STRING_LIST(STRING_INIT_LIST)    
};
```

And if we want a 1-to-1 corresponding look-up table containing the sizes of each string:

```
#define STRING_SIZES(str) (sizeof(str)-1),
const size_t sizes[] = 
{
  STRING_LIST(STRING_SIZES)
};
```

---

Complete example containing both a look-up table version as well as a directly compile-time processing version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STRING_LIST(X)                     \
  X("Small text message")                  \
  X("Slightly larger text message")        \
  X("A really large text message that "    \
    "is spread over multiple lines")

int main (void)
{
  #define STRING_INIT_LIST(str) str,
  char *textMessages[] = 
  {
    STRING_LIST(STRING_INIT_LIST)    
  };
  
  #define STRING_SIZES(str) (sizeof(str)-1),
  const size_t sizes[] = 
  {
    STRING_LIST(STRING_SIZES)
  };

  puts("The strings are:");
  #define STRING_PRINT(str) printf(str ", size:%zu\n", sizeof(str)-1);
  STRING_LIST(STRING_PRINT)

  printf("\nOr if you will:\n");
  for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof(textMessages)/sizeof(*textMessages); i++)
  {
    printf("%s, size:%zu\n", textMessages[i], sizes[i]);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
The strings are:
Small text message, size:18
Slightly larger text message, size:28
A really large text message that is spread over multiple lines, size:62

Or if you will:
Small text message, size:18
Slightly larger text message, size:28
A really large text message that is spread over multiple lines, size:62
```

The machine code of this boils down to printing a bunch of strings and constants from memory, no overhead `strlen` calls at all.

Answer (score 0):

[`strlen`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strlen/) maybe?

```
size_t size = strlen(textMessages[2]);
```

Comment: Why compute this number at runtime when it can be determined at compile time?

Comment: @Jens: Not unless you also know the string at compile time.

Comment: @Tudor, yes - you _do_ know the length at compile time (the question says "String Literal")

Comment: Worth noting that this will most likely be optimised out and replaced with the actual length of the string literal at compile time (providing compiler optimisation is turned on). See also @privatepolly's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `strlen()` library method to get the length of a string.  `sizeof` will give you the size of `textMessages[2]`, a pointer, which would be machine dependent (4 bytes or 8 bytes).