# Compile time size of string literal in array of string literals

Tags: c++, c, embedded, string-literals, compile-time-constant

I'm looking to find the length of a C-string literal at compile time.
Given the definitions:

```
static const char * const   header_left[] =
{
    "         |          |  Raw  |  Raw  |",
    "         |          | Start |  End  |",
    "Interval#| Duration | Point | Point |",
    "---------+----------+-------+-------+",
};
const unsigned int  rows_in_header = sizeof(header_left) / sizeof(header_left[0]);
```

**How do I find the length of string literal `header_left[2]` without using `strlen`?**

In this question, [Determining the Length of a String Literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541739/determining-the-length-of-a-string-literal), there is a comment to declare the array as `header_left[][4]`.  I prefer not to use this kind of declaration as there is a tendency for the number of strings to change without changing the quantity constant.  I like having the compiler calculate the quantity of strings (see the `rows_in_header` definition) and the length of each string.

This is for an embedded system and the strings are *block written* to a serial port.  The serial port function takes a pointer to the data and the length of the data as parameters.  The serial port code is optimized for block writes.  The preference is not to use `strlen` because that wastes performance time.

I am using C99 with IAR Embedded Workshop on an ARM7TDMI platform.
I have included the `c++` tag because this also involves C++ and we will be migrating the code to C++ after first product launch.

Comment: So you cannot change the definition at all? E.g. macro magic or C++ magic..

Comment: For `static const char * const   header_left[]` the length is irrelevant, since that's an array of pointers. Did you perhaps want `static const char header_left[][sizeof "Interval#| Duration | Point | Point |"] = { ... };`?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Would I need to duplicate the text in your case, once for the `sizeof` and other time between the `{` and `}`?

Comment: @DyP: I have had experience debugging issues that were caused from the capacity of the array not matching the number of elements declared in the array.  For example, I could declare the array as [][64] and each element was [][32].  This would leave 32 slots of undefined values. Or 32 nul characters sent to the serial port.

Comment: Yes, you might want to use a macro for it to avoid the duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the advice in the linked answer is wrong. as it has the indexes reversed.  The declaration should be more along the lines of this:

```
static const char header_left[][40] =
{
    "         |          |  Raw  |  Raw  |",
    "         |          | Start |  End  |",
    "Interval#| Duration | Point | Point |",
    "---------+----------+-------+-------+",
};
```

The left-most index can still be provided by the compiler, and indicates the count of strings.  The strings themselves must be a fixed char array, which you could provide an upper bound on (40, in this example).  You'll get a compile-error if any string exceeds that length (including null terminator).  The potential downside for your purposes is wasted space.

In any event, you can't have the compiler deduce both sizes for you - that of both arrays - and jagged arrays aren't supported in C++.

Comment: If each element in the array is a fixed length, is it still considered a *jagged array*?

Comment: No - a jagged array is an array of arrays, with the nested arrays of variable size.  In C++ you really only have one-dimensional arrays, the elements of which must be fixed size (compile time).  These can be nested to provide an approximation of multi-dimensional arrays.  But only the most significant (outermost) array can have its size deduced.

Answer (score 5):

A stringref class can handle this if you desire.  It seems simpler than most other answers, and handles situtations where the rows are different lenghts:

```
struct stringref {
    //this is for convenience, but isn't used in this sample
    stringref(const char* p, size_t l=0) :ptr(p), len(l?l:strlen(p)) {}
    //construct from string literals
    template<size_t l> stringref(const char(&p)[l]) :ptr(p), len(l) {}
    //convert to const char*
    operator const char*() const {return ptr;}
    const char* get() const {return ptr;}
    //retrieve the length
    size_t length() const {return len;}
private:
    const char* ptr;
    size_t len;
};

stringref header_left[] =
{
    "         |          |  Raw  |  Raw  |   ",
    "         |          | Start |  End  | ",
    "Interval#| Duration | Point | Point |      ",
    "---------+----------+-------+-------+",
};

int main()
{
    const char* ptr = header_left[0]; //conversion possible
    printf("%d\n", header_left[0].length());
    printf("%d\n", header_left[1].length());
    printf("%d\n", header_left[2].length());
    printf("%d\n", header_left[3].length());
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=e244267379f84e21409db9ec39da5765-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba

Answer (score 1):

Macro magic! (>= C99)
Requires at least 2 rows.

Note I don't use `char const*` but `char const[...]` here, i.e. arrays, because it's possible and guarantees all rows have the same length.

Edit: subtracted -1 from `length_of_row` to get rid of the `'\0'`.

```
#include<cstddef>
#define CREATE_HEADER(X, ...) \
  static const size_t length_of_row = sizeof(X)/sizeof(X[0]) - 1; \
  static const char header_left[][length_of_row+1] = { X, __VA_ARGS__ }; \
  static const size_t rows_in_header = sizeof(header_left) / sizeof(header_left[0]); \

CREATE_HEADER(
    "         |          |  Raw  |  Raw  |",
    "         |          | Start |  End  |",
    "Interval#| Duration | Point | Point |",
    "---------+----------+-------+-------+",
);
```

---

- `sizeof(X)/sizeof(X[0])` yields the length of the first string (row)
- `static const char header_left[][length_of_row]` is an unbounded array of arrays of `length_of_row` char; same as `typedef char const row[length_of_row]; row header_left[] = {...};`

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=7be12a566c06274fc6df138fd614e1bd-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba  works better than I expected.

Comment: @MooingDuck That is, `-1` for the `\0` I assume?

Comment: No, I thought your answer was wrong, so coded it, and it was right.  So I posted the code for future doubters.

Comment: @MooingDuck Ok :) nevertheless I've subtracted `-1` and changed the variable name, `column` is actually misleading since it's a table.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the `header_left[2]` string and use `sizeof(...) - 1`

```
static const char header_left_2[] = "Interval#| Duration | Point | Point |";
static const char * const   header_left[] =
{
    "         |          |  Raw  |  Raw  |",
    "         |          | Start |  End  |",
    header_left_2,
    "---------+----------+-------+-------+",
};
const unsigned int  rows_in_header = sizeof(header_left) / sizeof(header_left[0]);
const size_t header_left_2_len = sizeof(header_left_2) - 1;
```